# Play can't find Assets in my routes

Tags: scala, playframework

This is perplexing situation that seems like it should be very simple.

I'm using Play 2.3.4.
In my routes file I have:

```
GET / controllers.Documentation.index
GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

My documentation controller:

```
object Documentation extends Controller {
  def index = Action { Ok(views.html.documentation()) }
}
```

And my template `documentation.scala.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
</head>
</html>
```

This all compiles, but when I try to access the route `/`, I get a stack trace with the message:

```
Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Assets]]
```

This could only seem to be possible if the `routes` object referred to in the template doesn't have an `Assets` field, but I can't find a hint in the docs that this should ever happen.

Curiously, if I attempt to use the two-argument form of `at` in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="@routes.Assets.at("public", "stylesheets/main.css")">
```

...I get a compilation error `too many arguments for method at: (file: String)play.api.mvc.Call`.  It's as if `Assets` is defined at compile time, but not at run time.

What is going on?

Comment: can you try specifying the full path of the assets folder instead of just /public 

`GET /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce your error. It works just fine for me.